# jquery simple modal help on window load

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I'm trying to something like this  if in the html there is a div called "#super" load it in the simple modal if not do nothing.  I managed to do this with the my skill :D which is none:  to load the modal if the #super exists, but it still loads doesn't matter if it exitst or not.  PLease help  I'm absolute noob on jquery.

```
    if( $('super') ){    $("#super").modal({onOpen: function (dialog) {

    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
        dialog.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
            dialog.data.fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
}});
```

I'm using this jquery plugin [link text](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If #super does not exist, nothing will happen. So, the following should fit your needs:

```
$("#super").modal({onOpen: function (dialog) {
    dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
        dialog.container.slideDown('slow', function () {
            dialog.data.fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine.

Comment: Thanks, but it still loads as blank modal window if I change  #super to #superbas or whatever I need it not to show at all if div #super not exists in the html :)

Comment: What error are you getting? Do you have a link or more sample code? Can you post a working example of your issue on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Fixed :) You missed one braket in the code :)  forgot to cloe this "modal({on"  Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what it is that you want to do, in the if/else conditions, but to test for the existence of something:

```
if ($('#super').length) {
    // it exists, do stuff
}
else {
    // it doesn't exist, do other stuff. Or nothing
}
```

I'm sorry I can't be more specific, but I've not worked with the dialog/modal plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this check

```
if( $('#super') )
```

will always return true, since the jQuery function always return a jQuery object which is not a false value.

Instead try this

```
if( $('#super').length > 0 )
```